Show that $S(M) \leq 5a^2$
The problem
Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a cube of edge a. On $[BC']$ we consider a point $M$ and write $S(M)=AM^2+CM^2+D'M^2$
a) Show that $S(M) \leq 5a^2$
b) Determine the position of point $M$ so that $S(M)$ is minimal
my idea
the drawing

By the theorem of Pythagoras, we get that $AM^2=MB^2+AB^2=MB^2+a^2$ and $D'M^2=MC'^2+D'C'^2=MC'^2+a^2$.
So $S(M)=2a^2+BM^2+MC^2+MC'^2$ and we need to show that $2a^2+BM^2+MC^2+MC'^2 \leq 5a^2 <=>BM^2+MC^2+MC'^2 \leq 3a^2$
I have no idea what to do forward. I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

I think you have a problem if M = B'. Do you mean S(M) >= 5a^2?

As a next step to solving you can now just consider [BC']. Drop some perpendiculars from M to BC and from M to CC' and keep going with pythagoras

@AdamDougall Nope, i mean $S(M) \leq 5a^2$

Let's use a coordinate system with origin at $B$, the $x$-axis along $BC$ and $y$ along $BB'$. Then the coordinates of point $M$ will be $(x,x)$ (since it is moving on the $BC'$ diagonal), with $x\in[0,a]$. Then $BM^2=x^2+x^2$, $MC'^2=(a-x)^2+(a-x)^2$, $MC^2=(a-x)^2+x^2$. If you add them all together, you need to prove $$x^2+(a-x)^2\le a^2$$or $$x^2-ax\le 0$$
The last inequality is true between the roots of the quadratic, $0$ and $a$. The minimum will coincide with the minimum of the parabola, at $x=a/2$.

Thanks so much for your answer! Is there any way of solving this problem without functions or axes, I haven't learned about them yet.

Ah, by [BC’] you mean the line BC’? I haven’t seen that notation before. I thought you meant the face containing B and C’

Draw a perpendicular from $M$ to $BC$, say to $M'$. Let $BM'=x$. Then $BM^2=BM'^2+M'M^2=2x^2$. Similarly, $MC'^2=2(a-x)^2$ and $MC^2=x^2+(a-x)^2$. You get the same result

@Andrei Thanks! Now i understand! One more question: I don't understand how you calculated when the minimum occurs, idk what a parabola is

@Andrei Can you tell me if my idea is right? we have to find when the minimum of $x^2+(a-x)^2$ occurs. If we apply AM-GM we get that $x^2+(a-x)^2 \geq 2x(a-x)$, with the equality when $x=a-x$ so the minimum of that sum occurs when $x=\frac{a}{2}$ Correct me if my idea is wrong. Thanks

@Andrei Also, when i demonstrate that $x^2-ax \leq 0$, can i divide by x and have to demonstrate that $x-a \leq 0$ which is true because $x \leq a$?

@IONELABUCIU If you want to divide by $x$, and also keep the direction of inequality, you also need to say that $x>0$. Note that $x=0$ is also a solution

@Andrei Then can i take case where $x>0 $ and where $x=0$? Also is my idea for point b) right? Thanks!

You are correct for part b.

We have
$$BM^2 + MC'^2 \le BM^2 + MC'^2 + 2BM.MC'$$
$$BM^2 + MC'^2 \le (BM + MC')^2$$
Note that $BM + MC' = BC' = \sqrt{2}a$.
Also note that $MC \le a$ (why?).
You did most of the job.

Thanks for your answer! What about point b)?

@IONELABUCIU We looked at $BM^2 + MC'^2$ and $MC^2$, and we want to minimize their sum. It will be good to check what is the minimum of each of these two, and at what point does it happen? We will be lucky if both become minimum at the same point. Additional hint: $BM^2 + MC'^2$ is minimum where $BM.MC'$ is maximum (why?).

Can't we use AM-GM? $BM^2+MC'^2 \geq 2BM^2*MC'^2$  and the equality holds if $MC'=BM$. MC will be minimum if $MC \perp BC'$ so again if $M$ is the midpoint of BC'. is my idea right?  Correct me if I'm wrong?

@IONELABUCIU Yes your idea is right.

(only, there is a typo in the way you wrote AM-GM: right hand side shouldn't have squares!)
